# How to resume laptop by pressing any key on internal keyboard

Tags: suspend, power-management

I have a ThinkPad x1 carbon 7th gen laptop with Ubuntu desktop.

I want to wake the laptop from suspend using the built-in keyboard.

I have googled a lot looking for posts on this. I have not found a way.

Can anyone help?

Edit:

- I have ubuntu desktop 21.10.
- I have also tried Pop-os 21.10, Manjaro KDE, Kubuntu 21.10, and some others.
- I can close the lid, it sleeps, and opening the lid wakes it.
- A usb connected mouse wakes it every time the mouse is nudged.

Comment: I don't have a ThinkPad, but my laptop suspends when I close the lid and wakes up when I open the lid. Does your ThinkPad not do that? If not, have you set it up to hibernate rather than sleep? Please edit your question and add all the new information.

Comment: I just checked: If I suspend the laptop by clicking on the Suspend icon from the top drop-down menu, I can press the <Space Bar> to wake the laptop. This should be normal. In other words I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the version of Ubuntu you’re running? I have the 5th generation X1 Carbon and do not see the same issue 